# How can I destroy AWS nodegroup when it doesn't appear in CloudFormation and only seems to exist when trying to delete parent cluster or create new?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, cluster-computing, eksctl

Cards on the table, I'm a newcomer to `AWS` so my ignorance is likely the source of my issue.

Sharing the output from my terminal I think is the best way to describe my issue so:

I discovered my issue when I tried to spin up a 4 node `AWS EKS` cluster via `eksctl create cluster --name atp-dev --node-type m5.large --nodes 4`

Here is the output from that command:

```
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  eksctl version 0.49.0
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  using region us-west-2
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  setting availability zones to [us-west-2a us-west-2b us-west-2d]
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  subnets for us-west-2a - public:192.168.0.0/19 private:192.168.96.0/19
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  subnets for us-west-2b - public:192.168.32.0/19 private:192.168.128.0/19
2021-09-25 10:52:06 [ℹ]  subnets for us-west-2d - public:192.168.64.0/19 private:192.168.160.0/19
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  nodegroup "ng-a477426f" will use "ami-0adca766413605f27" [AmazonLinux2/1.19]
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  using Kubernetes version 1.19
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  creating EKS cluster "atp-dev" in "us-west-2" region with un-managed nodes
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  will create 2 separate CloudFormation stacks for cluster itself and the initial nodegroup
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  if you encounter any issues, check CloudFormation console or try 'eksctl utils describe-stacks --region=us-west-2 --cluster=atp-dev'
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  CloudWatch logging will not be enabled for cluster "atp-dev" in "us-west-2"
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  you can enable it with 'eksctl utils update-cluster-logging --enable-types={SPECIFY-YOUR-LOG-TYPES-HERE (e.g. all)} --region=us-west-2 --cluster=atp-dev'
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  Kubernetes API endpoint access will use default of {publicAccess=true, privateAccess=false} for cluster "atp-dev" in "us-west-2"
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  2 sequential tasks: { create cluster control plane "atp-dev", 3 sequential sub-tasks: { wait for control plane to become ready, create addons, create nodegroup "ng-a477426f" } }
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  building cluster stack "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster"
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [!]  1 error(s) occurred and cluster hasn't been created properly, you may wish to check CloudFormation console
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [ℹ]  to cleanup resources, run 'eksctl delete cluster --region=us-west-2 --name=atp-dev'
2021-09-25 10:52:07 [✖]  creating CloudFormation stack "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster": AlreadyExistsException: Stack [eksctl-atp-dev-cluster] already exists
    status code: 400, request id: 550e6a9d-d919-4a34-a012-7bc362f07c5a
Error: failed to create cluster "atp-dev"
```

I checked `CloudFormation` console like it suggests but there are no stacks to interact with I try following directions from the output with `eksctl utils describe-stacks --region=us-west-2 --cluster=atp-dev` which gives me a whole lot of information.

I can't really parse because this is where my understanding of all this ends:

```
2021-09-25 10:57:38 [ℹ]  eksctl version 0.49.0
2021-09-25 10:57:38 [ℹ]  using region us-west-2
2021-09-25 10:57:39 [ℹ]  stack/eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90 = {
  Capabilities: ["CAPABILITY_IAM"],
  CreationTime: 2021-09-22 18:18:00.55 +0000 UTC,
  DeletionTime: 2021-09-23 03:53:22.696 +0000 UTC,
  Description: "EKS nodes (AMI family: AmazonLinux2, SSH access: false, private networking: false) [created and managed by eksctl]",
  DisableRollback: false,
  DriftInformation: {
    StackDriftStatus: "NOT_CHECKED"
  },
  EnableTerminationProtection: false,
  Outputs: [
    {
      OutputKey: "FeaturePrivateNetworking",
      OutputValue: "false"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90::InstanceRoleARN",
      OutputKey: "InstanceRoleARN",
      OutputValue: "arn:aws:iam::988496401707:role/eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715-NodeInstanceRole-TR0AX0LF3N6J"
    },
    {
      OutputKey: "FeatureLocalSecurityGroup",
      OutputValue: "true"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90::InstanceProfileARN",
      OutputKey: "InstanceProfileARN",
      OutputValue: "arn:aws:iam::988496401707:instance-profile/eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90-NodeInstanceProfile-ZUE15KQVO72E"
    },
    {
      OutputKey: "FeatureSharedSecurityGroup",
      OutputValue: "true"
    }
  ],
  RollbackConfiguration: {

  },
  StackId: "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:988496401707:stack/eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90/6b591dc0-1bd1-11ec-9bec-0a0320ad966b",
  StackName: "eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90",
  StackStatus: "DELETE_FAILED",
  StackStatusReason: "The following resource(s) failed to delete: [SG]. ",
  Tags: [
    {
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name",
      Value: "atp-dev"
    },
    {
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name",
      Value: "ng-7b715a90"
    },
    {
      Key: "eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name",
      Value: "atp-dev"
    },
    {
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-type",
      Value: "unmanaged"
    },
    {
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/eksctl-version",
      Value: "0.49.0"
    },
    {
      Key: "eksctl.io/v1alpha2/nodegroup-name",
      Value: "ng-7b715a90"
    }
  ]
}
2021-09-25 10:57:39 [ℹ]  stack/eksctl-atp-dev-cluster = {
  Capabilities: ["CAPABILITY_IAM"],
  CreationTime: 2021-09-22 18:02:51.122 +0000 UTC,
  Description: "EKS cluster (dedicated VPC: true, dedicated IAM: true) [created and managed by eksctl]",
  DisableRollback: false,
  DriftInformation: {
    StackDriftStatus: "NOT_CHECKED"
  },
  EnableTerminationProtection: false,
  Outputs: [
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::SubnetsPrivate",
      OutputKey: "SubnetsPrivate",
      OutputValue: "subnet-0b82f725a2a3635e0,subnet-013021889c8604724,subnet-0ecc53da4fe6b3dde"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::SubnetsPublic",
      OutputKey: "SubnetsPublic",
      OutputValue: "subnet-0f7457b575c99d0c3,subnet-044fa1e27da8b0c7e,subnet-03a4577caf8947eda"
    },
    {
      OutputKey: "FeatureNATMode",
      OutputValue: "Single"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::ServiceRoleARN",
      OutputKey: "ServiceRoleARN",
      OutputValue: "arn:aws:iam::988496401707:role/eksctl-atp-dev-cluster-ServiceRole-S4KL2UIIWWH"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::Endpoint",
      OutputKey: "Endpoint",
      OutputValue: "https://OUTPUTKEY.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-ATP-dev-cluster::SharedNodeSecurityGroup",
      OutputKey: "SharedNodeSecurityGroup",
      OutputValue: "[REDACTED]"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-ATP-dev-cluster::VPC",
      OutputKey: "VPC",
      OutputValue: "[REDACTED]"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::ClusterSecurityGroupId",
      OutputKey: "ClusterSecurityGroupId",
      OutputValue: "[REDACTED]"
    },
    {
      OutputKey: "ClusterStackName",
      OutputValue: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster"
    },
    {
      OutputKey: "CertificateAuthorityData",
      OutputValue: "[REDACTED]"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::SecurityGroup",
      OutputKey: "SecurityGroup",
      OutputValue: "[REDACTED]"
    },
    {
      ExportName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::ARN",
      OutputKey: "ARN",
      OutputValue: "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:988496401707:cluster/atp-dev"
    }
  ],
  RollbackConfiguration: {

  },
  StackId: "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:988496401707:stack/eksctl-atp-dev-cluster/4d4a7bf0-1bcf-11ec-9822-028a7f03527f",
  StackName: "eksctl-atp-dev-cluster",
  StackStatus: "CREATE_COMPLETE",
  StackStatusReason: "Export eksctl-atp-dev-cluster::VPC cannot be deleted as it is in use by eksctl-atp-dev-nodegroup-ng-7b715a90",
  Tags: [{
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name",
      Value: "atp-dev"
    },{
      Key: "eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name",
      Value: "atp-dev"
    },{
      Key: "alpha.eksctl.io/eksctl-version",
      Value: "0.49.0"
    }]
}
```

Comment: When you checked the CloudFormation console, did you select the correct region? You should select `US West (Oregon) us-west-2` in the top right corner in the AWS console. Afterwards you should be able to see the CloudFormation stack.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I did make sure I was in the right region.

Answer (score 1):

There are two great apps for listing and removing almost any `AWS` resource, including yours case.

- `awsls` is for listing `AWS` resources
- `awsrm` is for removing `AWS` resources

## `awsls` is for listing `AWS` resources

[jckuester/awsls: A list command for AWS resources](https://github.com/jckuester/awsls)

> awsls supports listing of [over 250 types of resources](https://github.com/jckuester/awsls#supported-resources) across 100 different AWS services. The goal is to code-generate a list function for every AWS resource that is covered by the Terraform AWS Provider (currently over 500). If you want to contribute, [the generator is here](https://github.com/jckuester/awsls/blob/master/gen).

## `awsrm` is for removing `AWS` resources

[jckuester/awsrm: A remove command for AWS resources](https://github.com/jckuester/awsrm)

> This command line tool follows the [Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well) of `doing only one thing and doing it well`:
>
> It simplifies deleting over [250 AWS resource types](https://github.com/jckuester/awsrm#supported-resources) across multiple accounts and regions.
>
> Like other Unix-like tools, `awsrm` reveals its full power when combining it via pipes with other tools, such as [`awsls`](https://github.com/jckuester/awsls) for listing AWS resources and `grep` for filtering by resource attributes.

## E.g. removing `aws_eks_cluster` with `awsrm`

To remove **all** `aws_eks_cluster`s from your account, you may want

```
awsls aws_eks_cluster | awsrm
```

To remove `aws_eks_cluster` from **specific region**:

```
awsls aws_eks_cluster -r us-west-1 | awsrm -r us-west-1
```

To remove `aws_eks_cluster` from **specific profile and region**:

```
awsls aws_eks_cluster -p <yourprofile> -r us-west-1 | awsrm -r us-west-1  -p <yourprofile>
```